# Collect all dictionary values with the same key within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have several dictionaries within a list, that follow this convention:

`data = [{'name': 'Alessandra', 'age': 24}, {'name': 'Sasha', 'age': 37}, {'name': 'Jason', 'age': 42}]`

I want to separate out the list by the keys, to give this output:

```
names = ['Alessandra', 'Sasha', 'Jason']
ages = [24, 37, 42]
```

Can this be done?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It's in the post -- I don't know how to extract the values associated with the same key from 3+ dictionaries within the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can using list comprehensions

```
names = [item['name'] for item in data]
ages = [item['age'] for item in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple comprehension lists as follows to separate those two:

```
names = [d['name'] for d in data]
ages = [d['age'] for d in data]
```

If you want a more generic version that just looks at the first dict's keys as a reference you can use the following for loop, even though I wouldn't recommend it as this can easily break your code if you define variables that way, and Pylance will detect this as erroneous code as you don't explicitly define the variable names as variables but rather a string:

```
data = [{'name': 'Alessandra', 'age': 24}, {'name': 'Sasha', 'age': 37}, {'name': 'Jason', 'age': 42}]

for key in data[0].keys():
   exec(f"{key}s = [d[key] for d in data]") # adding an s to variable names.

print(names)
print(ages)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data=[{'name': 'Alessandra', 'age': 24}, {'name': 'Sasha', 'age': 37}, {'name': 'Jason', 'age': 42}]

 name = []

 age = []

 for item in data:

    name.append(item.get("name"))
    age.append(item.get("age"))

print(name)

print(age)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

A general solution creating a dictionary of lists.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    {'name': 'Alessandra', 'age': 24}, 
    {'name': 'Sasha', 'age': 37}, 
    {'name': 'Jason', 'age': 42}
]

transformed = defaultdict(list)

for _ in data:
    for k, v in _.items():
        transformed[k].append(v)
```

Resulting `transformed`:

```
{'name': ['Alessandra', 'Sasha', 'Jason'], 'age': [24, 37, 42]}
```